# Reorder the Range with specific way

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm looking for a way to reorder the given range to have the first, last, middle one, then the middles of the middles and so on..., If we look at 0-15 range it will be like this: So neighbor members will come only at last iteration.

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
>
> 0 15 8 4 12 2 6 10 13 1 3 5 7 9 11 14

Any ideas for a good algorithm?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The basic idea is to recursively build a generator/list of "middles", than use this list/generator values as indices of elements to take on each step. However, writing a method that would build such a list/generator is a bit non-trivial (read: slightly more than I can afford to do right now), so it's left for you.

Comment: I don't really like to have a recursion in it, but will try thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses a queue instead of recursion.

13 and 14 are positioned differently from your example, but if you consistently consider the middle of a even-length list to be the element just after the middle, 14 comes first:

```
import collections

def reorder(seq):
    '''Yield items from seq reordered to http://stackoverflow.com/q/33372753/
    seq can be any sequence, eg. a list or a Python 3 range object.
    '''
    # output first and last element before all the middles
    if seq:
        yield seq[0]
    if len(seq) > 1:
        yield seq[-1]

    # a queue of range indices (start, stop)
    queue = collections.deque([(1, len(seq)-1)])
    while queue:
        start, stop = queue.popleft()
        if start < stop:
            middle = (start + stop) // 2
            yield seq[middle]
            queue.append((start, middle))
            queue.append((middle+1, stop))

print(list(reorder(range(16))))
#[0, 15, 8, 4, 12, 2, 6, 10, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this makes sense for me.